# Google Sign-In not working with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have this code

```
public class SignInActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private static final String TAG = "SIA";
    private static final String USER_ID = "USER_SI_SUCCESS";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 103;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        // Initialize authentication and set up callbacks
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // GoogleApiClient with Sign In
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,
                        new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                                .requestEmail()
                                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                                .build())
                .build();
    }

    public void processSignIn(View view){
        Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);        
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleGoogleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleGoogleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.getStatus());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Successful Google sign in, authenticate with Firebase.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct);
        } else {
            // Unsuccessful Google Sign In, show signed-out UI
            Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign-In failed.");
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        showProgressDialog(getString(R.string.profile_progress_message));
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult result) {
                        handleFirebaseAuthResult(result);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {                       
                        handleFirebaseAuthResult(null);
                    }
                });
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }

    private void handleFirebaseAuthResult(AuthResult result) {
        // TODO: This auth callback isn't being called after orientation change. Investigate.
        dismissProgressDialog();
        if (result != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "handleFirebaseAuthResult:USER_ID");
            Intent porstSIIntent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            porstSIIntent.putExtra(USER_ID, result.getUser().getUid());           
            SignInActivity.this.startActivity(porstSIIntent);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    //Firebase depedencies
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.2'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1'
    ///compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    // Required for OneSignal, even if you have added FCM.
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:hfrecyclerview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.atlassian.commonmark:commonmark:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.atlassian.commonmark:commonmark-ext-gfm-tables:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.atlassian.commonmark:commonmark-ext-gfm-strikethrough:0.6.0'
    compile 'ren.qinc.edit:lib:0.0.3'
    compile project(':drawer')

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.1'
}
```

Google Sign-In is not working at all and I am getting the following Log

```
E/SIA: handleSignInResult:Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}
E/SIA: Google Sign-In failed.
```

**Important**: Couple of months ago this code was working, but now it won't. I don't know why. Please guide me.

Comment: `firebase-common:9.0.2'` << Needs to match other firebase versions (though you can also remove it; `common` is included by the others)

Comment: please check this. I hope this will help you https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/issues/22

Comment: Status 12501 often indicates there is a problem with the configuration defined in your google-services.json file.  Check the values for package name, SHA1 key, etc.  Maybe try generating and downloading a new file.

Comment: do openjdk and oracle jdk generate different fingerprints ?  it was issue with `SHA1 certificate fingerprints` hence now solved...

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this case is SHA1 fingerprint in Firebase console.
Go to project settings and paste SHA1 fingerprint that you currently use.

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Keytool will prompt for password. Enter: `android`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have correct google-service.json and enabled google login in authentication -> sign in method  in firebase console

Comment: As I told it was working couple of moths ago, I have done all the configuration stuff in  firebase console and a correct google-service.json is there in my app